# Need help with some surprising classifications by naiveBayes

Tags: classification, sample-size, sample, naive-bayes, bayes

We are trying to do a POC on using `NaiveBayes` to classify an establishment by the category.

We loaded the following  training set in R.

```
NAME_1,NAME_2,CHANNEL_5
Vanilla,Bar,Bar &  Grill
Zen,Bar,Bar &  Grill
cafe,havana,Bar &  Grill
cafe,hollywood,Bar &  Grill
monaco,grill,Bar &  Grill
grill,grill,Bar &  Grill
hunai,asian,Bar &  Grill
Apple,Institute,School
devry,Institute,School
usu,College,School
suny,university,School
fashion,school,School
theater,study,School
Burger,King,Hamburger
Mighty,Burger,Hamburger
one,Burger,Hamburger
wendy,sandwich,Hamburger
Burger,Heaven,Hamburger
Burgler,Burger,Hamburger
```

Columns 1 & 2 make up the name of the establishment. Column 3 is the class.

```
library(e1071);

new_training_data <- read.table("C:/Users/test/08_jul_13_training.txt",
header=TRUE , sep="\t");

 model1<-naiveBayes(new_training_data[,1:2],new_training_data[,3],laplace
 =2);

test_data <- read.table("C:/Users/test/test1.txt", header=TRUE , sep="\t");

predict(model1, test_data[,1:2],type = c("class","raw"));
```

The test_set with the expected category and the actual result from NaiveBayes classifier are given below.

```
NAME_1,NAME_2,Expected_category,Actual_Result_from_Naive_bayes
my,Bar,Bar &  Grill, Bar &  Grill 
cafe,milano,Bar &  Grill, Hamburger
Teaching,Institute,School, Bar &  Grill
devry,Institute,School, Bar &  Grill
beauty,school,School, Bar &  Grill
fashion,school,School, Bar &  Grill
theater,school,School, Bar &  Grill 
Burger,Baja,Hamburger, Hamburger   
Burger,Big,Hamburger, Hamburger 
Pepsi,Cola,Hamburger, Bar &  Grill
Burger,Supreme,Hamburger, Hamburger 
Burger,King,Hamburger, Hamburger
```

`my bar` is correctly classified as `Bar & grill`. However  `Cafe Milano` is classified as `Hamburger` instead of `Bar & Grill`.
statistically speaking the probability of `Bar` in `my Bar` is no different from `Cafe` in `Cafe Milano`.
Any pointers in how `NaiveBayes` is coming up with these results will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it really make sense to classify on the _name_ of an establishment?

Comment: Unfortunately this is the only option we have.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is related to factors, which are a data type in R which often behave unexpectedly.

I don't have your test data, but when you use the classifier to predict from a new data point, you have to make sure that the possible levels of `NAME_1` and `NAME_2` are *exactly* the levels which appear in the training data. If the training and test data come from different text files, then this is very unlikely to be the case.

Your first three lines of code work fine for me.

Let's just suppose you want to classify a single new data point with `NAME_1 = n1` and `NAME_2 = n2`. Here is how you could do it.

```
    pred <- function(model, n1, n2, type){
      n1 <- factor(n1, levels = levels(new_training_data[,1])) 
      n2 <- factor(n2, levels = levels(new_training_data[,2]))
      predict(model, data.frame(NAME_1 = n1, NAME_2 = n2), type)      
   }
```

Now it should work with your model. The following behave for me as expected:

```
pred(model1, "Teaching", "Institute", "class")
pred(model1, "cafe", "milano", "class")
pred(model1, "beauty", "school", "class")
```

You could extend this to data frames so you could classify all of your test data at once. I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you. The approach suggested by you is working. Can you suggest how this can be extended to classify all test data at once without using a loop.

Comment: After loading your `test_data`, do this: `for (i in 1:2) test_data[,i] <- factor(test_data[,i], levels=levels(new_training_data[,i]))`. Words in `test_data` which did not appear in the training data will now appear as `NA`. Then your `predict` should work.

Answer (score 0):

it looks to me like you're doing a multinomial naive bayes.  If you look at the tables component of the model object, you should (according to the docs) see tables of conditional probabilities given the target class.

How many classes are you attempting to predict?  Have you tried 1-3 grams on the incoming words?  It kind of looks like you're using up to two 1-grams; is that correct?

Also, please put your data into tables so we can see which text goes in which column?